# Как создать всплывающую подсказку определённой формы?

Tags: css, qt, gui, pyqt, qwidget

Доброго времени суток! Нужно создать всплывающую подсказку определённой формы как на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также подсказка должна выводиться строго под серединой кнопки и не зависить от положения курсора впределах кнопки. Буду благодарен дельным советам как к этому вообще подступиться? В работе использую PySide.

Comment: Нет, а он тут поможет?

Comment: Спасибо, а как Qt'шному StyleSheet'у объяснить, что это?)

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп. Я, пожалуй, потру свои комменты, т.к. не уверен, что они имеют какой-то практичный смысл. Изначально невнимательно прочёл сабж и теги. Прошу прощения.

Comment: Да, в этом и проблема, был бы Qt'шный Bootstrap...

Comment: Да, в определённых рамках. Типа QToolTip это прямоугольный виджет, могу ему цвет фона поменять, а форму никак. Всякие хитрости с картинками тоже не сработают, тк opacity так же не воспринимается в QSS. Хотя в документации приводится пример с opacity